# Position operator '$' is not working in Mongo PHP 5.5

Tags: php, mongodb

Here I need to insert another array data where there is already an existing record in MongoDB.

**Example**:

Already existing record in db:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "name" : "main",
    "sample_details" : [ 
        {
            "detail_no" : 1,
            "email" : "test@gmail.com",
            "name" : "test",
        }, 
        {
            "detail_no" : 2,
            "email" : "test12@gmail.com",
            "name" : "test12",
        }
    ],
}
```

Suppose I need to insert one more array data in "sample_details". Here is my code, but the position operator "$" is not supporting. May I know the exact solution for my query:

**Code**:

```
$array = array(
    'sample_details.$.detail_no' => 3,
    'sample_details.$.email' => "test123@gmail.com",
    'sample_details.$.name' => "test123",
);

$this->mongo_db->update(table_name,array('_id'=>1),array('$set'=>$array),array('multiple'=>true));
```

Comment: If anyone know, please help me

Comment: What do you want to do with the query if not exist insert the record?

Answer (score 0):

To insert data into array you want to use operators like [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/update/push/), [$pushAll](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/update/pushAll/) or [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/update/addToSet/).

You can't use positional operator because citing its [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/):

> the array field must appear as part of the query document.

Also it only makes sense when you're updating an array's element and you don't know its index, not inserting new things.